# What is the upper limit of ADF string variable?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there any character limit on ADF string variable ? I am trying to store a big script in ADF variable , which seems to be working fine but this is a dynamic script so I wonder if there is any storage limit to it? My use case is that based on some tabular input , I am forming a script and need to send it to some compute , I didn't find any other solution apart from using a string variable.

Comment: This seems like a risky approach to me.  The script will be harder to maintain and edit, it may be within the limits now but about the future if the script needs to expand?  If it’s SQL script make it into a stored proc or if it’s Python, Scala, c# or SparkSQL store it in a notebook, eg Databricks or Synapse Notebook.

Comment: the script is auto generated based on some tabular input which is just some metadata , it's not a sql script, it's an adx script , so it gets submitted to an adx cluster ultimately -- the issue with using other tools to generate the script such as python etc , i will need a dedicated compute just for that whereas ADF has its own out-of-the-box compute (integration service)

Comment: character count of the script as of now is 600k + , seems to be functioning fine. Looks like the limit is pretty high :)  , still it would be nice to know the limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't upper limit of the ADF string variable. No documents talked about it and can't find any useful messages.

But I tested and found that you can set variable value length until you get the  browser **SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXECEEDED** error. I put a 16M string to the variable value:
[image]

You also could set a big size string as the variable value to prove that. The key is that I don't know the how to get the `SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY`. I googled and found nothing about it.

Hope it's useful for you.